# Artifactory repository pull replication using exclude patterns

Tags: caching, properties, replication, artifactory

I have created a remote repository in a server by setting up pull replication of a  repository in another server; since that repository is large I have added exclude patterns conditional to the setup to exclude all these artifacts that I don't need in my remote repository; everything seems to work fine, however my system logfile in reports a lot of warning messages for those exclude artifacts:

```
2018-05-30 19:45:38,267 [replication-consumer-1527709500001-0] [WARN ] 
(o.a.r.s.RepositoryServiceImpl:1061) - Cannot set properties on 
'xxxx-cache:yyyyyy/zzzzzzz/195383/aaaaaa/bbbbbb': Item not found
```

(I intentionally removed the actual names of my dirs and artifacts)
as you can see the message is about the cache repository created

Do you know how can I eliminate those warnings and get a cleaner system logfile?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you have stumbled upon a known issue:  https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16597

You are welcome to vote and watch.